# strike doesn't work on LaTeX

Tags: bug

Marked down strike command doesn't work on LaTeX. Here is an example:

<strike>Here is a stroked out text including the following LaTeX equation $A = B$ but strike is not working on it!</strike>

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because of how MathJax interacts (or rather does not interact) with the surrounding text. Since the surrounding text could get arbitrarily large before encountering a markup command, it's not surprising this will happen. There's no real way to deal with this.

Comment: I.e. this is a problem with MathJax and its compatibility with HTML , and it cannot be fixed by SE.

Comment: that's my claim, yes.

Comment: If there were a way of striking through an equation in LaTeX, you could get around this problem. Does anybody know whether there is?

Comment: @Peter, there should be something for it as there are \overline and \underline. Maybe a question for [tex.se]?

Comment: Here's the answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text